# boost::filesystem::path(std::wstring) throw exception

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

this code:

```
boost::filesystem::is_directory("/usr/include");
```

work fine.

both this code:

```
boost::filesystem::is_directory(L"/usr/include");
```

throw an exception:

> terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>   what(): 
>   locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name
>   not valid

OS - Linux Mint

boost-1.43

gcc-4.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use wide strings on Linux. You don't need them..
2. What happens that it tries to convert wide string to normal one and for this
   creates a locale and probably this locale is not configured in your system.

   Bring output of commands:

   ```
   locale 
   locale -a
   ```
3. GCC-4.6 wasn't released yet `;-)`, check if this works with ordinary compiler. Probably libstdc++ wasn't build well.